# AngularJS - Filter Dropdown List with text box and submit option value

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have seen http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/typeahead#typeaheads to allow a user to be able to type in a text-box and filter results in a pseudo-dropdown.

What I am looking to do, is modify this / provide a better method of allowing a user to type to filter select box results, with the intention of submitting the selected option value.

Unfortunately, there is no actual select box in above example.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ? 
http://plnkr.co/edit/lg5YN53JVzRUv8UmWTp8?p=preview

You can also modify this to get your options from an API.